# Bootstrap select error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

[image: problem pic]

I just want a form with an input and a select, but bootstrap is doing me this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Morada</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEstado">Estado:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="inputEstado" value="Agendado">
            <option >Agendado</option>
            <option >Por Marcar</option>
            <option >Falta Material</option>
            <option >Inspeção</option>
            <option >Faturado</option>
            <option >Ligado</option>
            <option >Recebido</option>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try closing the `<select>` tag

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Please be sure to avoid changing the markup of other peoples' code. The problem you erased in the question by adding a closing tag was the root cause of OP's problems.

Comment: @TylerH Yes that was my bad. But when I saw that the question was already answered and I tried to flag this question as "simple typographical error" but I didn't have any flags left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use correct html code formating.
Make sure you have closed all tags properly.
Its seems you havent close the select tag.